# Counting no of delimiters for very large file(~50 GB) with shell scripts

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file 'test.txt' which contains over 2,000,000,000 records.

Each record is on a separate line and has multiple fields separated by a delimiter `|` .

Each row should have equal number of fields, but the problem is there can be cases where row has less or more delimiter

Can someone please suggest a most efficient way in Unix for larger files, by which I can identify the row. (Like getting count of `|` characters in each row in the file and throw error if `|` is less or more)

I tried

```
awk -F '|'  'NF != 35 {print NR, $0} ' test.txt
```

but while pressing enter i was getting number from 1 then 2(after second third enter button) then 3(after third enter button)

Comment: I'm not sure if you can improve a lot on the performance of this using Unix utilities (if any) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="|";}{ if (NF != 36) print $0}' yourFile.txt
```

Explanation :
`BEGIN` is used to do pre-processing in awk scripts before the main pattern matching is done. Over here I set the delimiter to match `|` instead of the default white space

`NF` is an internal variable used by awk to determine how many feilds are present in one row of your record. You wanted to check if a row contained more than or less than 35 delimiters.

That is equivalent to saying if there are more than or less than 36 feilds in a given row.

see this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-awk-language-to-manipulate-text-in-linux) for a good introduction to awk scripting

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question, but `awk` shouldn't behave differently depending on file size, and the command you posted shouldn't prompt you to press Enter. Are you sure that the there isn't just some (console) buffering going on and the command would run to completion all the same without any input?

You could try this, which would feed `awk`'s `STDIN` as many newlines as it wants to read:

```
yes '' | awk -F '|'  'NF != 35 {print NR, $0} ' test.txt
```

As for efficiency, apart from proper function, there really isn't any way to perform the desired operation any more efficiently than by looking at every single line (runtime *O(n)* where *n* is the number of lines).